# How to find the running time of the operation: array.length() in java or C#

Tags: arrays, time

This might be a dumbquestion, but does anyone know the running time of finding the length of an array in java/c# using `array.length()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O(1).
The running time is in the Order of 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question that can be answered that easily. The runtime depends on various factors, including but not limited to the hardware you run it on.

You should include more details to get a more detailed answer on this.